# Why does optional chaining cause an overlapping accesses error?

Tags: swift, option-type

```swift
struct SomeStruct {
    var foo: String?
    var bar: String?
}

var someOptional: SomeStruct? = SomeStruct()

someOptional?.bar = someOptional?.foo
```

This code causes the following error on the last line.

> Overlapping accesses to 'someOptional', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable

If I replace the last line with the following, then the program works as expected.

```swift
let foo = someOptional?.foo
someOptional?.bar = foo
```

Why is the first example causing an error, and why does the alternate version (which I would assume to be identical) not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlapping accesses to 'urlComponents', but modification requires exclusive access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46126574/overlapping-accesses-to-urlcomponents-but-modification-requires-exclusive-acc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structs are value types, so when you do `let foo = someOptional?.foo`, the **value** of `someOptional?.foo` is copied into the local variable `foo`. Hence in your next line, `someOptional?.bar = foo` you don't access `someOptional` to get the value of `foo` anymore, but you access the value of the local variable directly.

This is why `someOptional?.bar = someOptional?.foo` is not equivalent to the above solution and why saving the value to a local variable resolves the overlapping accesses error.

The cause of the error is also the fact that you are using value types. In the line `someOptional?.bar = someOptional?.foo` you are mutating an instance property of `someOptional` and hence mutating the instance `someOptional` as well, while at the exact same time accessing another instance property of `someOptional`.

If `someOptional` was a reference type, you wouldn't get that error, see below:

```
class SomeClass {
    var foo: NSString? // `NSString` is a reference type
    var bar: NSString?
}

let someOptionalClass: SomeClass? = SomeClass()
someOptionalClass?.bar = someOptionalClass?.foo

let fooRef = someOptionalClass?.foo
someOptionalClass?.bar = fooRef
```